# Lubuntu 16.04 need newet MPD

Tags: lubuntu, git, mpd

I just upgraded to Lubuntu V16.04, and the Ubuntu repository comes with v19.12 of MPD.

It seems to have some bugs that the https://www.musicpd.org/ says v19.21 (on git) may fix.

Can someone tell me how I might get the newer version?

Do I need to recompile? Or maybe someone has already done that?

Thanks for your help.

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear mpd here recommends using the version in the repos which for 16.04 is 9.12. https://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/install.html but if you truly want to try this out you may need to add ppa if you do not want to continually build from source from each version. [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/4990#4990) explains what a ppa is better than I can. However with the new version keep in mind the developers can make mistakes and put new bugs in and if it makes it worse for you can remove the ppa with http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ppa-purge which will remove anything else brought in by any ppa. But be warned these packages in ppas have not undergone security checks.

Comment: Thanks for the info, ianorlin. The current MPD version (0.19.12.1) has a bug whereby it locks up. The music gets stuck and repeats a 1/5 (or so) second chunk, kinda like old CD could do once in a while, and also, whatever client I am using at the time looses contact with MPD. I can restart the client, reconnect with MPD, tell it to pause, then play, and it continues for another while, maybe a day. The newest version (19.21) claims to have fixed that bug. I am gonna try, then I will come back here and post my results.